# Pre-populate Rails collection_select with ajax action (Rails 5 and jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to build an invoice app where every **invoice** has a line invoice **item(e.g. productname, cost, amount)**.

I want when i select **productname** from the from a **drop-down** list in the invoice item, an ajax is fired to query the **product database table** with **params[:product_id]**, gets the product **cost** from the database and hence populate the item cost instantly.

i.e. When a user select product name, that product cost shows up too instantly without typing it.

In the attached image below, my query_string returns JSON as expected, except for i dont know how to pass/display the returned **data** to the **cost_field**.

If i do **html(product.cost)**, i  get/return **[object, object]** at #notification and **undefind cost** in the rails console too.

My question is, how do i do something like this?  $("#notification").html(product.cost)

**MODELS:**

```
    class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true,  reject_if: proc {|a| a[:product_id].blank?}
      has_many :products, through: :item
    end

    class Item < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :invoice, optional: true
      belongs_to :item, optional: true
    end

    class Product < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :items
    end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
   class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


   def index
     @invoices = Invoice.all
   end

   def new
     @invoice = Invoice.new
     2.times {  @invoice.items.build }
   end

   def pricedata
    @product = Product.select(:id, :cost, :productname).where('products.id = ?', params[:product_id])

     respond_to do |format|
     format.html {  render html: @product.id }
     format.js #{ render js: @product}
     format.json { render json: @product }
   end

  private
     def invoice_params
        params.require(:invoice).permit(:name, :amount, items_attributes: [:qty, :price, :id, :product_id, :_destroy])
     end
```

**FORM**

```
     <p id="notification"></p>   # notice to keep my eyes on return obj

    ...

    <%= f.fields_for :items do |item| %>

     <span><%= item.label :product_id %>      </span>


     <span>       // # collection begins here
       <%= item.collection_select(:product_id, Product.all, :id, :productname,
            {prompt: "Select a product"}, 
            {class: 'selectors'  multiple: true })  
       %>
      </span>     // # collection ends here


     <span><%= item.label :qty %> </span>
     <span><%= item.number_field :qty %> </span>
     <span><%= item.label :price, class: "p_price"   %> </span>
     <span><%= item.number_field :price %> </span> 
     <span><%= item.check_box :_destroy %> Remove item</span>

    ...
```

**JAVASCRIPT / COFFEE**

```
  $(document).ready ->
    $('.selectors').on "change", ->
    selectOptions= $('.selectors option:selected')
    product_id = $(this).val()

    if selectOptions.length > 0
        selectOptions.each ->
            $.ajax({
                url: '/invoices/:id/pricedata?product_id=' + product_id,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                contentType: 'application/html'
                success: (product)-> 
                        $("#noticification").html(product)
                        console.log(product)
                    })
```

[image]

Comment: Following @max suggestion, i was able to solve the problem. I sent ajax request to **ProductController** directly like this.....    
                   $.ajax({
                         url: '/products/' + product_id,
                        .....
                         $("#notification").html(product.cost)
          
                          })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really overcomplicating it.  To get the details for a product you should just be sending an ajax request to a simple show action on `ProductsController`.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /products/:id
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end
end
```

Also you should not use a multiple select in this case as it would make the quantity and price ambiguous. Instead create a fieldset or div for each item row.
The [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) helper can be used to give a specific scope for each item:

```
<%= form_for(@invoice) do %>
  # ...
  <%= fields_for(:items) do |item| %>
    <!-- group each item in an element so you can find the associated inputs -->
    <div class="item">
     <!-- use a div to group inputs ands labels instead! -->
     <span><%= item.label :product_id %>      </span>
     <span><%= item.collection_select(:product_id, Product.all, :id, :productname,
            {prompt: "Select a product"}, 
            {class: 'selectors'  multiple: true })  %>
     </span>     // # collection ends here
     <span><%= item.label :qty %> </span>
     <span><%= item.number_field :qty %> </span>
     <span><%= item.label :price, class: "p_price"   %> </span>
     <span><%= item.number_field :price %> </span> 
     <span><%= item.check_box :_destroy %> Remove item</span>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you want an explanation why your current solution does not works its because `.where` returns a collection of records and not a single record. While you could fix it with `.take` or by using `.find` your approach is broken and can be done in a much simpler and more conventional way.

Comment: Thanks @max. Solved. i will post my solution right away